# Open default mail client with a link

Tags: asp.net, html, mailto

I have an HTML link on my ASP.NET page. When the user clicks the link, an Outlook window will open. However, it changes the URL on my page also to `mailto:reddy@yahoo.com`.

How to stop it?

```
<a href="#" 
   onclick="window.open('mailto:reddy@yahoo.com?Subject=upport','','200','200');"
   style="color: White">Contact Support</a>
```

Comment: This may not matter if you're building an intranet app, but I am finding more people using 'cloud' email like gmail or hotmail and these links don't work for them. No 'mail client' to launch.

Comment: @n8wrl - good point.  That's a design issue - so @Goutham needs to remember to have a textual description of who to send mail to.  Generally, I avoid using a mailto link at all costs anyway.  if I want to send mail, I'll use System.Net.Mail and send it myself from code.  If the client needs to send the email, it IS always better to just instruct them to do so, for exactly the reason you pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it in a window.open.  Just show the link on the page, as a normal link, and Outlook will open in a new window anyway, because it's a different program.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
<a href="mailto:reddy@yahoo.com?Subject=upport" style="color: White">Contact Support</a>
```

Comment: +1.  Same answer as me, but with a code sample instead.  I was going to add the code sample, but since you beat me to it...

Comment: <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?Subject=upport">Contact Support</a>. i have this link on the footer of the master page.. you code works for some pages and does not work for some pages

Comment: Post the HTML output or if possible a link to the page in question we can play with. Btw, the mailto: links don't open outlook, they open the default mail client whatever that happens to be

Comment: the page url is changing to mailto:"..."  the\ HTML source code is generic.. it says page cannot be displayed.. which is generic..

Comment: No, open up the page with the links on it in the web browser, right click it and press "view source" or words to that effect. Then find the source code for the working and not working links and post each, specifying which is which. I'm beginning to wonder if something is messing with the link somehow as the code above should work

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, you're navigating to a URL that is a `mailto`.

Can you switch to a regular anchor tag `mailto` link?

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?Subject=upport">Contact Support</a>
```

Comment: i have this link on the footer of the master page.. you code works for some pages and does not work for some pages..

Comment: when i click the link it is opening the new outlook window but it is also navigating to href="mailto:foo..." and changing the URL of the page...

Comment: @Goutham: make sure you're making this change everywhere. The plain anchor link will NOT navigate anywhere or change the URL of the page.